# Hover not working with Internet Explorer/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, microsoft-edge

I have a menu that is displayed on the location where the user clicks on the web page. This is how it works:

- a hidden DIV with menu content is present on the bottom of the page
- click event triggers a function
- DIV is displayed by altering it's style (to trigger the hover CSS)
- DIV is positioned on the mouse click location
- DIV's display style is unset after a small fraction of time (0,5 seconds)
- the user has the option to use the menu as long as he hovers over it

This works in Chrome/Opera, but not in Internet Explorer/Edge. There's a 1px (my guess, since I can't measure it) distance the user has to move the mouse to trigger the hover on Internet Explorer/Edge (within the 0,5 seconds time frame).

Of course, I can fix this problem by repositioning the menu 1px left/up, but the point of this question is to try to understand why is this happening.

This is the HTML stripped of unnecessary code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).click(function(e) {
    menu = document.getElementById("m");
    menu.style.display = 'block';
    menu.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
    menu.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
    setTimeout(function(){ menu.style.display = ''; }, 500);
});
</script>

<style>
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#m
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
}
#m:hover
{
    display: block;
}
#m ul
{
    color: #1E90FF;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
#m li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#m li:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="m">
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why you use click event in jQuery and style setting in vanilla JS? `$('#m').css({display: 'block', left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY})`.

Comment: I'm testing, combining code, therefore JS/jQuery mixup.